# Struts 2 Display Tag Sorting and Pagination Issues

Tags: java, sorting, struts2, pagination, displaytag

We have a Struts2 Application in which we have implemented Dojo Tabs and `DisplayTable`s.
There are 3 Tabs, each including a JSP in which data is displayed through Display Tables.
The issue is when we perform Sorting / Pagination in one tab, the same gets applied to the other two tabs as well.

Can anyone please suggest how to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the same action to paginate those tables. Once the request is made in one table it affects others because they are sensible to those requests. The solution would be to map different actions for each table, so it would not affect the state of the other tables.  See the example [Struts2 pagination using display tag](http://javastoreroom.blogspot.com/2013/06/struts2-pagination-using-display-tag.html).